# Display ng-options based on condition

Tags: angularjs

Here is my data

```
This.dynamicCmb = [{
                id: 1,
                label: 'aLabel',
                subItem: ['aSubItem1','aSubItem2','aSubItem3']
            }, {
                id: 2,
                label: 'bLabel',
                subItem: [ 'bSubItem' ]
            }];
```

I want to display 'subItem' data depending on the value I give i.e, either id or label. if I search any one it should display value.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedColumn" /> //Textbox to take either id or name value
    <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="GetCmbValue()" /> //On click of button it should load dropdown
    <select ng-options="item.name for item in vm.selectedColumn.subItem" ng-model="vm.selected"></select>
```

.js file

```
 This.GetCmbValue = function () {
// I should load drop down value here
            };
```

for eg: if I give '1' in textbox then subItem of '1' should display. If I give 'alabel' in textbox then also subItem of 'alabel' should display. It should search either on id or label whatever I give. Please help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can attach filter to your ngOption. So that every time you type value in textbox, it will filter data accordingly.
We bind the output of textbox to the filter.

.js file

```
    app.filter('itemFilter', function() {

    return function(input,val) {
        var out = new Array();
        angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
            if (item.id == val || item.label == val) {
                out = out.concat(item.subItem);
            }
        });
        return out;
    };
});
```

HTML File

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="val">
<select data-ng-options="item for item in dynamicCmb | itemFilter : val" data-ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your select code by this

```
     <select ng-options="item.name for item in vm.selectedColumn.subItem|filter:{Id:vm.selectedColumn}"   ng-model="vm.selected"></select>
```